# Pass Elastic Job Process ID to target DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, elasticsearch, jobs

I am using Azure Elastic Job for SQL maintenance activities like Rebuild Indexes, purging data, etc.

So for multiple job runs, I want to track those operation at my target DB. I wanted to track them based on the elastic job process id.

Is there anyway we can capture & send the elastic job process id to the target db via stored procedure.

Please note I have created my jobs to run periodically in every hour and weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Elastic job process details are stored in **jobs.job_executions**

```
SELECT * FROM jobs.job_executions
```

[image]

We cannot use stored procedures or directly query to get the results from cross databases, we need to configure elastic query the databases to get the Elastic job agent table data to Target database table.

You will need to configure the below steps(with sample syntax):

1. Create a Master Key

   ```
   CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<master_key_password>';
   ```
2. Create Database Scoped Credentials

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ABC 
   WITH IDENTITY = '<username>', 
   SECRET = '<password>';
   ```
3. Create External Data Source

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE DatasourceName WITH 
   (LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net', 
   DATABASE_NAME = 'TargetDB’, 
   CREDENTIAL = ABC, 
   ) ;
   ```
4. Create External Table

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[job_executions] 
   ( [job_execution_id] nvarchar(256), 
     [Job_name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,  
     …) 
    WITH 
   ( DATA_SOURCE = DatasourceName 
   ) ;
   ```

Once you have defined your external data source and external tables you can query the Agent database table and use the data in Target Database.

For more details, please visit [Cross-Database Query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6445/azure-sql-cross-database-query/)